# How to Log-in with Firebase in Swift UI?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I can create user through my code and get in to the next view but I can not log in with that mail address and password I just created. On the other hand, when I create a user in Firebase authentication page without programmatically, I can log in with that mail address and password. I don't know why this is happening.

My login button's codes are as following...

```
Button(action: {
                self.verify()
                
            }) {
                
                Text("Log In")
}

                    
func verify(){
    
    if self.mail != "" && self.pass != ""{
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.mail, password: self.pass) { (res, err) in
            
            if err != nil{
                
                self.error = err!.localizedDescription
                self.alert.toggle()
                return
            }
            
            print("success")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "status")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("status"), object: nil)
            
        }
    }
    else{
        
        self.error = "Please fill all the contents properly"
        self.alert.toggle()
    }
}
```

My signUp button's codes are as following...

```
Button(action: {
            self.register()
        }) {
            
            Text("Sign Up")
                
        }

func register(){
    
    if self.mail != ""{
        
        if self.pass == self.repass{
            
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.mail, password: self.pass) { (res, err) in
                
                if err != nil{
                    
                    self.error = err!.localizedDescription
                    self.alert.toggle()
                    return
                }
                
                print("success")
                
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "status")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("status"), object: nil)
            }
        }
        else{
            
            self.error = "Password mismatch"
            self.alert.toggle()
        }
    }
    else{
        
        self.error = "Please fill all the contents properly"
        self.alert.toggle()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think is better you handle your Sign In listener AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle I recommend to check this doc. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#listen_for_authentication_state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Sign In in Firebase I recommend some updates in your code:

1. Use completion to your Sign In and Sign Up functions, this way you know for sure that Firebase is answer you.
2. Handle listener AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle. This listener gets called whenever the user's sign-in state changes.

API Authentification:

```
    class AuthService {
      static func signInUser(email: String, password: String, onSucces: @escaping() -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage : String) -> Void ) {
         Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authData, error) in 
            if (error != nil) {
               print(error!.localizedDescription)
               onError(error!.localizedDescription)
               return
             }   
             //Sign In Code
             onSuccess()
       }

       static func signUpUser(email: String, password: String, username: String, onSucces: @escaping() -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage : String) -> Void ) {
    
      Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authData, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            onError(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        //Sign Up Code
        onSuccess()  
         
    }
}

  }
```

in your View or ViewModel:

```
    func verify() {
    
       if self.mail != "" && self.pass != ""{
           AuthService.signUpUser(email: email, password: password, username: username, onSucces: {
               print("Sign In!")
           }) { (error) in {
               print("Error \(error)")
           })
    }
}
```

Class Session, to handle Auth Listener

```
    class SessionAuth : ObservableObject {
       @Published var isLoggedIn = true
       var handle : AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
        
         func listenAuthentificationState() {
         
              handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
                 if let user = user {
                     //You are log in 
                     // Your login process code
                     self.isLoggedIn = true
                 }
                 else {
                      //You are not 
                      self.isLoggedIn = false
                 }    
         }  
    }
```

Your main View:

```
    struct ContentView: View {

       @ObservedObject var session : SessionAuth //or EnvironmentObject

       func listen() {
           session.listenAuthentificationState()
       }

       var body: some View {
   
          Group {
            if session.isLoggedIn {
                MainLoggedView()
            }
            else {
                SignInView()
            }
          }.onAppear(perform: listen)
       }
    }
```

Comment: what should I write in scenedelegate part into let contentView = mainView(?) for parameter session

Comment: you could set var session as @EnvironmentObject instead of ObservedObject in the code below and add the environment at SceneDelegate, for example:
        let contentView = ContentView() 
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(SessionAuth()))
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

Comment: I still can not login if I create a user through simulator, but if I create a user in firebase by adding a new user then I can log-in through simulator with that user. I'm stuck.

Comment: I add signUp function maybe it helps to you, i suppose you already did add authentification by email in your firebase Auth project

Comment: Why did you use if let user = user in listenAuthentificationState function. User is not used anywhere.

Comment: auth and user are the escaping from addDidStateListener, to know if user is auth you check that an user exists https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#addstatedidchangelistener_:

Comment: I understand that but in your code you never used it and it worked also :) xcode gives yellow error message thats why I’m asking

Comment: I don't use because is a sample code :) you can access user user.email user.uid, maybe you have more user data in your firestore ...

Answer (score 0):

In if else()
you need to "return ();"
and,
you should create login activity in programa manner.
FOR bETTER ResulT.